# Deserialize collection into outer array

Tags: java, collections, jackson, deserialization

I would like to serialize the following class into an array containing the property `num` and the items in `collection`.

```
public class Foo {
  private final int num;
  private final Collection<String> collection;
  ...
}
```

I would like:

```
[num, "a", "b", "c"]
```

I can get part of the way there by annotating Foo with `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)` but that only gets me:

```
[num, ["a", "b", "b"]]
```

How might I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write custom serializer and deserializer for your `POJO` class.
Serializer:

```
class FooJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Foo> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Foo value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        generator.writeStartArray();
        generator.writeNumber(value.getNum());
        if (value.getCollection() != null) {
            for (String item : value.getCollection()) {
                generator.writeString(item);
            }
        }
        generator.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

Deserializer:

```
class FooJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Foo> {
    @Override
    public Foo deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        String[] array = parser.readValueAs(String[].class);
        int num = 0;
        Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (array.length > 0) {
            num = Integer.valueOf(array[0]);
            for (int index = 1; index < array.length; index++) {
                collection.add(array[index]);
            }
        }

        Foo foo = new Foo(num, collection);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Now, you have to link your `POJO` class and custom serializer/deserializer implementation:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = FooJsonSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = FooJsonDeserializer.class)
class Foo {
}
```

Simple usage:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(11, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
System.out.println("Serialize to JSON:");
System.out.println(json);
System.out.println("Deserialize to POJO:");
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class));
```

Above program prints:

```
Serialize to JSON:
[11,"a","b","c"]
Deserialize to POJO:
Foo [num=11, collection=[a, b, c]]
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The valid `JSON` serialization is the one you are getting, in the sense that the resulting string can be deserialized into the original object.

For the output you are after, you probably will need to do it manually.